# Does "pick on" in thus text mean to frighten or to choose?

Tags: word-meaning

> I like to be outdoors, **pick on** people my size, and read books. I'm a patent lawyer, and relatively good-looking for a nerd. I love Ironman triathlons, but usually come in near last in my age group. I can fly a single-engine plane.
>
> I like a man with a big brain (not head) and strong legs. Ideally, someone who understands "the road less traveled," and the value of a patent. If you also happen to have a fast bicycle (not the motorized kind), dabble in swordfighting, or have mastered cartography, then you are my man.

My second concern has to do with the word "size". When she says **people my size** what does it mean? The same age? Or the same height?

Answer (score 2):

It is a reference to the saying ["Pick on someone your own size"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pick+on+somebody+your+own+size), which is used when some competition or confrontation isn't fair because one person or entity has an inherent advantage over another.

An example might be a boxing match where one fighter is much larger and stronger than his opponent. Another example might be a huge corporation with lots of money and Lawyers suing an individual without the same resources.

By saying "I pick on people my own size", she's saying she likes fair competition, or possibly that she's not afraid to stand up for what she believes is right, but won't "pick on" someone who isn't able to defend themselves.